# Revert transaction payable error with abi.encodeWithSignature

Tags: solidity, abi, bytecode, abi.encodewithsignature

I have two contracts:

**Validate.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;



contract Validate {

    function validate(address _verifier, bytes memory _validityData) public view {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = _verifier.staticcall(_validityData);

        require(success && abi.decode(result, (bool)), "Request/certificate invalid");
    }


}
```

**Verify.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import "./Validate.sol";

contract Verify {

    Validate public validate;

    function verify(address _owner, uint256 _requestId) public view{
        bytes memory _validityData = abi.encodeWithSignature("isRequestValid(uint256)",_requestId);
        validate.validate(_owner, _validityData);
    }

}
```

When I deploy Verify.sol and pass `_Owner = msg.sender` and `_requestId = 1` (some arbitrary uint256), it gives me the following error:

`Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.`

Any ideas why I'm getting this error. I'm a newcomer. Appreciate a full explanation.

**Update:**
Folks asked me to add some more details on this. Below are complete details. What I posted above was the two functions that I extracted as a result of debugging.

Below is a link to the actual contract that I extracted this functions from:

[https://github.com/energywebfoundation/origin/blob/master/packages/traceability/issuer/contracts/Issuer.sol][1]

`Issuer.sol` makes a call into `RegistryExtended.sol` which makes a call to `Registry.sol`

Below is the process that I followed:

1. Import `Issuer.sol` and all the dependencies to Remix.
2. deploy `Issuer.sol`
3. Run function initialize(uint256 _certificateTopic, address _registry) pass in 010101 for _certificateTopic and msg.sender for _registry
4. Run function requestCertification(bytes calldata _data) external returns (uint256) pass in 0x00 for _data and verify "_id":1 was issued.
5. Run function approveCertificationRequest(uint256 _requestId, uint256 _value) public returns (uint256) pass in _id = 1 and _value = 200

Getting the following error:

Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

When I debug, the error comes from Registery.sol following function:

function _validate(address _verifier, bytes memory _validityData)

In this case I see: _owner is being passed in for _verifier and abi.encodeWithSignature("isRequestValid(uint256)",_requestId) for _validityData

Comment: Show the code you use to make the call Verify contract

Comment: That is a generic error message that appears when the transaction failed. Why it failed? Without code we can just speculate, a require or assert statement failed, it run out of gas, some variable wasn't properly initialized, etc.

Comment: Thank you both! The full contract is saved here: https://github.com/energywebfoundation/origin/blob/master/packages/traceability/issuer/contracts/Issuer.sol

Comment: `Issuer.sol` makes a call to 'RegisteryExtended.sol` which makes a call to `Registry.sol`

Comment: Updated my question above with more details.